# How to Make Api Action to hit on Application_Error() in GlobalAsax

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api

I have an **Application_Error() in Global.asax** defined with some error handling code that will make the error redirect to the **ErrorController** to its specific action(say Error500). I have this working good for **Web Actions** like ActionResult..

But an WebApi action like IHttpActionResult or HttpResponseMessage doesnt redirect/hit on **Application_Error()** for GlobalAsax in WebApi. 
Im writing the action as for eg.

```
public IHttpActionResult PersonDetail(int id)
{           
   if(id == null)
   {
     throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
   }
   else
   {
     return Ok();
   }
}
```

But this will display me as Error500 on that url/page but doesnt take me to Application_Error(). So what do i need to do make it hit Application_Error() so i can redirect it to ErrorController to handle it more nicely.. ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use custom exception handler, in that case, you can to consider specific behavior for each exception in only one method (not catch block in every error prone code blocks), look at this simple example:

```
public class MyExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is SqlException)
        {
            //do something...
        }
        else if (context.Exception is HttpListenerException)
        {
            //do something...
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else...
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you have to register your custom exception handler in global.asax:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyExceptionHandler());
```

Comment: Means i have to create this 'MyExceptionHandler' class and register the above line in Application_Start() ? and when some exception is thrown in an api action will it hit the Handle method ?

Comment: @VirajKawthankar Yeah, with this mechanism, for all exceptions, Handle method will catch them. You could also log exception details there.